# User Registration in Devise through API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rest, api, devise

I have recently started developing REST APIs with rails 5. I am trying to do User crude actions through API calls. I have set up a basic devise for users.

In my routes I have this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, :controllers => {sessions: 'sessions', registrations: 'registrations'}
end
```

I created two separate controllers sessions_controller and registrations_controller to override devise methods and make it accept JSON format.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    respond_to :json
end
```

and

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
    respond_to :json
end
```

I am trying to register a user passing in the following data:

```
{  
    user: {
        email: me@gmail.com,
        password: password,
        password_confirmation: password
    }
}
```

I get a status 200. but in my rails server I'm getting the following error:

```
Started POST "/users" for 23.233.9.94 at 2016-12-22 08:22:11 +0000
Processing by RegistrationsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"Payload: {  \r\n    user: {\r\n        email: me@gmail.com,\r\n        password: password,\r\n        password_confirmation: password\r\n    }\r\n}"=>"[FILTERED]"}
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

So I basically have 2 questions. 
How do I format the JSON so that my devise controllers recognize it and save it to the database. 
And my second question is how do I pass in a CSRF token. A little example would really help me out here. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The data you posted is not a valid JSON. Your configuration seems okay, but I think if you pass valid JSON, controllers will start recognizing it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your JSON is not valid.You need to enclose the string with double quotes

```
{  
    "user": {
        "email": "me@gmail.com",
        "password": "password",
        "password_confirmation": "password"
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't know I have to wrap the data with resource name. Wasted 2 hours

Comment: same issue. Thanks