# sending post request to devise registrations using json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, post, devise, request

I want to use create a user account using postman, rails 5, and the devise gem. I added a username field to the devise user model and confirmed that it is working fine. However, when I send a post request to the Rails API, it is not creating the user as expected. Here is how the process goes through:

I'm sending this JSON post request to the URL: `http://0.0.0.0:3000/users/`

```
{
    "username": "username",
    "email": "name@example.com",
    "password": "password",
    "password_confirmation": "password"
}
```

Upon sending this request, I get the following response:

```
{
    "status": "ERROR",
    "message": "Could not create new user account",
    "data": {
        "email": [
            "can't be blank"
        ],
        "password": [
            "can't be blank"
        ]
    }
}
```

I created another Registrations Controller which inherits from Devise::RegistrationController. Here it is:

```
  1 module Api
  2   module V1
  3     class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  4 
  5       before_action :configure_permitted_parameters
  6       respond_to :json

  7       def new
  8         user = User.new(user_params)
  9       end
 10 
 11       def create
 12            user = User.create(username: params[:username], 
 13                         email: params[:email], 
 14                         password: params[:password],
 15                         password_confirmation: params[:password_confirmation])
 16      
 17         if user.save 
 18           render json: {status: "SUCCESS", message: "Created new user account", data: user }, status: :ok
 19         else 
 20           render json: {status: "ERROR", 
 21                         message: "Could not create new user account", 
 22                         data: user.errors}, 
 23                         status: :unprocessable_entity
 24  
 25         end
 26       end
 27       
 28       private 
 29       
 30       def user_params
 31         params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
 32       end
 33 
 34       protected
 35 
 36       def configure_permitted_parameters
 37         devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:username])
 38       end
 39 
 40     end
 41   end
 42 end
```

Any idea why I'm getting this response, and how to fix it? I'm grabbing the email and password from the `params` hash and passing it into the create function. I don't know why the response I'm getting states that it's empty

Answer (score 4):

You should format your parameters nested under "user" e.g.:

```
{  
"user": {
    "username": "username",
    "email": "name@example.com",
    "password": "password",
    "password_confirmation": "password"
  }
}
```

as seen on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46886325/4455570)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you change the drop-down in postman from `text` to `JSON (application/json)`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you have at the moment is that you are not accessing at the params correctly. if I am not wrong, your user params will come inside params[:user]

so you need to change this lines to:

```
user = User.create(username: params[:username], 
                   email: params[:user][:email], 
                   password: params[:user][:password],
                   password_confirmation: params[:user][:password_confirmation])
```

but to be sure, look at the server console and see the parameteres that comes in the request, you will see something like

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-05-22 14:56:56 -0400
Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"pQhz8qXPbK/lXhioL5H4iq6nxImOmtG9ya81Cuke6Ez+uqDKwNlhTMjv8spjcNhMmXFQMUAB+enlOHeZakwgow==", "user"=>{"email"=>"asdasdasasd@asdassdasd.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "terms_of_service"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
#<ActionController::Parameters:0x007fa5f6b457c8>
```

and there you can see the real structure that comes to the server on the request, talking about the params